# WP Subtitle Plugin Problem

Tags: plugins, php

I'm having some problems getting the WP Subtitle plugin to work.

After inserting the `<?thesubtitle()?>` or `<?getthe_subtitle($id)?>` into the index.php template I get a 'call to undefined function' error - inside or outside the loop doesn't seem to matter!

Thanks in advance

//Update

In most pages the following now works thanks to toscho's updated syntax

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="title-posts-container">
<h2 class="title-posts"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<p class="title-posts-strap"><?php the_subtitle(); ?></p>
</div>

<div class="content">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

But no such joy in index.php where the following fails

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="title-posts-container">
<h2 class="title-posts"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<p class="title-posts-strap"><?php the_subtitle(); ?></p>
</div>

<div class="content">

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Inserting what?

Comment: Ooops forgot to hit the code button around the php tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [correct syntax](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wp-subtitle-typo-the_subtitle-not-thesubtitle):

```
<?php the_subtitle(); ?>
<?php get_the_subtitle( $id ); ?>
```

Comment: Ok, this code doesn't produce an error - it simply does nothing.

Comment: Well this is curious, it does work on normal pages and page templates but not in index.php?!

Comment: Add a longer snippet to your original question demonstrating how exactly you use it in index.php. Outside of the loop it shouldn’t work if your index.php is an archive.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles If your front page is an archive and not a static page, then there is not page to choose a subtitle from. What do you expect to see?

Comment: The Homepage is static and the blog is using a News page to display posts - which is the code you're looking at the title and subtitle attributes are set in that page.

Comment: The news page is an archive and has no `$post`, hence no `$post->ID`, outside of the loop. Therefore there is no post to search a subtitle. Use `get_the_subtitle($your_custom_post_id)` to retrieve the subtitle you need.